# Java fx Image path

Tags: image, url, path, javafx

i have a problem with `javafx`' `ImageView`.

I try to load a simple `jpg`, as an image and add it to an `ImageView`.
But `Javafx` can't finde the resouce.

```
    Image image = new Image("image.jpg");
    ImageView iv1_1 = new ImageView();
    iv1_1.setImage(image);
```

the exception i get is this one:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

it is crashing in the line, where the image is created.

Here is a picture of the Project:
[enter link description here](http://puu.sh/dCyDk/03f55b0a3a.png)
(I am not allowed to post pictures.)

Answer (score 1):

Use getClass().getResource("image.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below example to load image using JavaFX.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LoadImage extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Load Image");

        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        Image img = new Image("javafx.jpg");
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
        sp.getChildren().add(imgView);

        //Adding HBox to the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(sp);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }    
}
```

Create one source folder with name Image in your project and add your image to that folder otherwise you can directly load image from external URL like following.

```
Image img = new Image(
    "http://mikecann.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/javafx_logo_color_1.jpg"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = new Image(new FileInputStream("image.jpg"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImageView view = new ImageView();
    view.setImage(image);
```